# ActionEvent stop

Tags: java, swing, button, actionlistener

How do I stop the action event of Button2 and more runs after Button1.
Button1 need to do only Button1 Action Event and stop then.

Please Help me, thank you

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if (ae.getSource().equals(button1)){
        System.out.println("Button 1");

    }

    if (ae.getSource() == button2){
        System.out.println("Button 2!");
    }
```

edit:

sorry, wrong code

in main:

```
Button1.addActionListener(this);
        jPanel1.add(Button1);
        Button2.addActionListener(this);
        jPanel1.add(Button2);
```

not in main:

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Object Button1 = null;
        if (!ae.getSource().equals(Button1)){
            System.out.println("Oben");
        }
        Object Button2 = null;
        if (ae.getSource() == (Button2)){
            System.out.println("Links");
        }


             }
```

if i press my Button1, i get "Oben"

if i press my Button2 i get "Oben", too

why i dont get "Links"

Comment: Action events don't loop unless told to do so. So I'm really confused as to that you're trying to get at here.

Comment: whats the issue in code

Comment: Attach separate listeners to the two buttons? What output are you expecting to see, and what do you actually see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. You are setting `Button1` and `Button2` to `null`
2. Your if-statements are layed out in such a way that more than one of them can run in a single invocation of `actionPerformed`

Try this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if(ae.getSource().equals(this.Button1)) {
        System.out.println("Button 1");
    } else if (ae.getSource().equals(this.Button2)) {
        System.out.println("Button 2");
    }
}
```

This code assumes that `Button1` and `Button2` are members of the class that the `actionPerformed` method belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

Take another look at your (edited) code.

```
Object Button1 = null;
if (!ae.getSource().equals(Button1)){
    System.out.println("Oben");
}
```

So what you're saying here is the following, which is going to evaluate true in both cases.

```
if (ae.getSource() != null)
```

This is why the result is always *Oben*.

If you are intending to compare against a different `Button1`, make sure to reference the correct the object. Without seeing the rest of the code it's hard to say, but you may mean to use (`this.Button1`);

Answer (score 1):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    Object Button1 = null;
    if (!ae.getSource().equals(Button1)){
        System.out.println("Oben");
    }
    Object Button2 = null;
    if (ae.getSource() == (Button2)){
        System.out.println("Links");
    }


         }
```

I'm afraid the above code make's little sense, and doesn't conform to usual practice. Firstly, buttons that perform different actions should have different listeners, except in special cases. This is not one of those special cases. Split up your code into:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
     System.out.println("Oben");
     // This is the actionPerformed method for button 1.
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
     System.out.println("Links");
     // This is for button 2.
}
```

Then simply bind to the relevant buttons.

Comment: As it is written, this solution doesn't make sense.  In order for there to be two methods with the same signature, they would have to belong to two different classes.

Comment: Correct, but I'm assuming OP knows what to do with these methods. I try to avoid just handing the code to the asker.